# Odoo - Is it possible to show both tax included and tax excluded total price in invoice lines ?

Tags: odoo, invoice, odoo-8

I try to show both columns in the account invoice form :

- total of an invoice line, tax excluded
- total of an invoice line, tax included.

I know that it is possible to set the tax object to be included or excluded in product price, but I don't see the way to show both in invoice form.

I already extended account.invoice.line as follow :

```
from openerp import api, models, fields
import openerp.addons.decimal_precision as dp

class cap_account_invoice_line(models.Model):

   _inherit = 'account.invoice.line'
   price_with_tax = fields.Float(string='Prix TTC', digits= dp.get_precision('Product Price'), store=True, readonly=True,)


    """
    @api.multi
    def button_reset_taxes(self):
        #I guess I should override this method but i don't know how
        #to calculate and load the total line with included tax 
        #into the field 'price_with_tax'
    """
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Victor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found :

from openerp import api, models, fields

import openerp.addons.decimal_precision as dp

class AccountInvoiceLine(models.Model):

```
 _inherit = 'account.invoice.line'


 price_subtotal_tax = fields.Float(compute='_compute_price_tax', string=' Total including tax', digits= dp.get_precision('Product Price'), store=True)




@api.one

 @api.depends('price_unit', 'discount', 'invoice_line_tax_id', 'quantity',

     'product_id', 'invoice_id.partner_id', 'invoice_id.currency_id')

 def _compute_price_tax(self):

     price = self.price_unit * (1 - (self.discount or 0.0) / 100.0)

     taxes = self.invoice_line_tax_id.compute_all(price, self.quantity, product=self.product_id,

                                                                              partner=self.invoice_id.partner_id)

     self.price_subtotal_tax = taxes['total_included']

     if self.invoice_id:

         self.price_subtotal_tax = self.invoice_id.currency_id.round(self.price_subtotal_tax)
```